# What triggers the pyqt dragLeaveEvent

Tags: drag-and-drop, pyqt4

When I'm dragging an item from a tablewidget, what triggers the the drag events, is it the QTableWidget, or the QTableWidgetItem?  Or, something all together different?  I need to alter my mimeData when it gets selected and is being dragged to a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured out my problem:

It's the `QTableWidget` that triggers the event.  The problem I was having was that I set `setDragEnabled(True)` after I was trying to use my overridden event function.